# spring-boot-maven-plugin @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: spring-boot, properties, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to use @ConditionalOnProperty while starting the application with the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

If I start the project with eclipse I just have to add `-Dexample=true` to the vm arguments.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty( name = "example", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false )
```

I tried to do the same with the spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
<jvmArguments>-Dexample=true</jvmArguments>
<jvmArguments>-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--example=true"</jvmArguments>
<arguments>
    <argument>-Dexample=true</argument>
    <argument>-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--example=true"</argument>
</arguments>
```

but none of these works.

If I add a profile

```
<jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=exampleProfile</jvmArguments>
```

which contains the argument `example:true` it works.

EDIT:

The exact argument is

```
<arguments>
    <argument>openapi.offline=true</argument>
</arguments>
```

but the property is still not found

```
- @ConditionalOnProperty (openapi.offline=true) did not find property 'offline'
```

My conditional:

```
 @ConditionalOnProperty( prefix = "openapi", name = "offline", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false )
```

Solution:

I had multiple

```
<jvmArguments> -example1 </jvmArguments>
<jvmArguments> -example2 </jvmArguments>
```

but they override each other. So I had to put them all in one jvmarguments field

```
<jvmArguments> -example1 -example2 </jvmArguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `-D`
Try this:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>....</version>
    <configuration>
      <arguments>
        <argument>--openapi.offline=true</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the response

the exact arguement is
openapi.offline=true

             `        <arguments>
                        <arguement>openapi.offline=true</arguement>
                     </arguments>`

but the property is still not found
`- @ConditionalOnProperty (openapi.offline=true) did not find property 'offline'`

`   @ConditionalOnProperty( prefix = "openapi", name = "offline", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false )`

Comment: ok . could you try adding `--` before the property . (edited the answer)

Comment: same error. but thanks

Comment: weird . if you add openapi.offline=true to your property file does it skip the bean creation ? (just for testing could you try it ) ?

Comment: yes if i add openapi.offline=true or if i build the project with mvn -Dopenapi.offline=true

Comment: - ConditionalOnProperty (openapi.offline=true) matched 
- ConditionalOnProperty (openapi.offline=false) found different value in property 'offline'

Comment: ok i found it out. I had multiple <jvmArguments> lines in my Pom, the kind of override each other, if i put everythin in one jvmArgument it worked. I will add an Solution to the Question.